# Протокол и интерфейс на Физическом уровне

Tags: сеть

Что есть протокол Физического уровня, а что есть интерфейс? В чем различие и есть ли оно?

В одном из источников прочел > Физический интерфейс определяется набором электрических связей и характеристиками сигналов. Интерфейс задает параметры, процедуры и характеристики взаимодействия объектов.

Другой источник > Физический протокол определяется характеристиками каналов связи, сигналами и разъемами портов.

Т.е. при связи компьютер-компьютер канал связи и характеристика передаваемых сигналов это протокол, интерфейс или все вместе?

Объясните пожалуйста. спасибо

Comment: Мне кажется, разобраться Вам поможет OSI :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Протокол может включать в себя несколько интерфейсов. Если в случае общения двух компьютеров интерфейсом может быть интерфейсная карта, её порт, канал между двумя компьютерами и характеристика сигналов этого канала, то в случае протокола физического уровня - он включает в себя все это сразу(совокупность этого всего и есть протокол)

Answer (score 0):

Интерфейс является фактической реализацией протокола.

Протокол - это описание того, как должен быть устроен интерфейс.

Comment: Согласно с учебником, который я прохожу у интерфейса тоже могут быть разные реализации, а протокол реализует так называемые "протокольные сущности". Я понимаю протокол, как виртуальная связь двух одноранговых уровней, а интерфейс - непосредственная(без промежуточных уровней), но в случае с физическим уровнем эти понятия наслаиваются.